# Python - Strings in a list in a pandas df row to column headers along with count as values

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas DataFrame `df` looks like -

```
fileName     objectsIdentified  objectName
file_01.jpg  1, 2, 3            obj1, obj2, obj3
file_02.jpg  2, 3               obj2, obj3
file_03.jpg  1, 2, 4, 2         obj1, obj2, obj4, obj2
```

`type(df['objectName'].iloc[0]` is list
`type(df['objectName'].iloc[0][0]` is string

**Question**: 
How can I get the items in objectName as separate columns with the counts as values?

**Expected output**:

```
fileName     objectsIdentified  objectName              obj1   obj2   obj3   obj4
file_01.jpg  1, 2, 3            obj1, obj2, obj3        1      1      1
file_02.jpg  2, 3               obj2, obj3                     1      1
file_03.jpg  1, 2, 4, 2         obj1, obj2, obj4, obj2  1      2             1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more line of:

```
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(df['objectName'].tolist()).stack()).sum(level=0).replace(0, ''))
```

To your code, then `df` will become:

```
      fileName objectsIdentified                objectName obj1  obj2 obj3  \
0  file_01.jpg         [1, 2, 3]        [obj1, obj2, obj3]    1     1    1   
1  file_02.jpg            [2, 3]              [obj2, obj3]          1    1   
2  file_03.jpg      [1, 2, 4, 2]  [obj1, obj2, obj4, obj2]    1     2        

  obj4  
0       
1       
2    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `concat` and `get_dummies` function in python to get the above:

```
df_result = pd.concat([df[['fileName','objectsIdentified']], pd.get_dummies(df['objectName'].apply(pd.Series))], axis=1)
```

I am assuming `df` is your initial data frame and `df_result` is your output data frame.

Comment: @ash16win I am seeing duplicate columns like 0_obj2 and 1_obj2